# Scrape Text From Iframe

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

How would I scrape text from an iframe with puppeteer.

As a simple reproducible example, scrape, `This is a paragraph` from the iframe of this url

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scrape an `iframe`'s text in puppeteer, you can use puppeteer's `page.evaluate` to evaluate JavaScript in the context of the page that returns the `iframe`'s contents.

The steps to do so are:

1. Grab the `iframe` Element
2. Get the `iframe`'s `document` object.
3. Use the `document` object to read the `iframe`'s HTML

I wrote this program that grabs `This is a paragraph` from the [link you provided](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events):

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_events');

    const iframeParagraph = await page.evaluate(() => {

        const iframe = document.getElementById("iframeResult");

        // grab iframe's document object
        const iframeDoc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        const iframeP = iframeDoc.getElementById("demo");

        return iframeP.innerHTML;
    });

    console.log(iframeParagraph); // prints "This is a paragraph"

    await browser.close();

})();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that this question already has an answer, but if maybe someone wants to go for another approach where you can grab the content from an iframe and use cheerio to traverse over the elements and get the text of any element you want - [you can find it here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54041256/9898824).